# SQL - Convert to date

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-convert

I have a numeric column in SQL which I need to convert to a date. The field is currently coming into the database as: `"20181226.00000"`.

I only need to the characters before the `" . "`. So i did a `SUBSTRING - CHARINDEX` looking for anything before the `" . "` . I then did a cast as `NVARCHAR`.

Now I'm getting `20181226` but I want this date field to populate like: 
`"MM/DD/YYYY"` .

My current SQL is:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUBSTRING(CAST('MYFIELD' AS NVARCHAR(50)) ,0, CHARINDEX('.', 'MYFIELD' , 0)),101)
```

Comment: Just change 101 to 103  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUBSTRING(CAST('MYFIELD' AS NVARCHAR(50)) ,0, CHARINDEX('.', 'MYFIELD' , 0)),103)

Comment: Why would you let a date value come into your database like that in the first place? Translate at the time it's inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Just change 101 to 103

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUBSTRING(CAST('MYFIELD' AS NVARCHAR(50)) ,0, CHARINDEX('.', 'MYFIELD' , 0)),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert it to what it actually is, a `date`, and then back to a `varchar` using the right style.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(max), convert(date, substring(convert(varchar(max), nmuloc), 1, charindex('.', convert(varchar(max), nmuloc)) - 1)), 101)
       FROM elbat;
```

I wasn't sure if it's a number or a string. If it's a string you don't need the `convert(varchar(max), nmuloc)`s.

However a side note: You should not store dates as numbers or strings. Use an appropriate data type like `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could achieve it like this.

```
declare @v_value numeric(18,5)=20181226.00000

SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(@v_value AS INT) AS VARCHAR),5,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(@v_value AS INT) AS VARCHAR),7,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(@v_value AS INT) AS VARCHAR),1,4) as V_OUTPUT

--Output
/*
V_OUTPUT
------------------
12/26/2018
*/
```

Best Regards,

Will

Answer (score 0):

First we have convert to varchar and then Date format

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, CAST(CAST('20181206.00000' as VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE), 103); dd/mm/yyyy

SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, CAST(CAST('20181206.00000' as VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE), 101); mm/dd/yyyy
```